# Disabling "code execution" in Xaml Designer causes toolbar for reenabling to disappear

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019, xaml-designer

I had a Xaml Designer Exception. I don't remember what the exception said. Then a window opened, where i could select from 3 options.(see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/designers/debugging-or-disabling-project-code-in-xaml-designer?view=vs-2015). I presses the options "click here to disable running project code and reload designer". After that i had another exception [image: Xaml Exception]. Furhtermore i have no visible toolbar for the xaml designer anymore. This was not the exception, that caused xaml designer to be disabled. I've tried enabling/disabling xaml designer in tools->options, ive also tried to repair my visual studio 2019 version. I don't know what else to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i feel really stupid now. The toolbar is not visible when the xaml designer code execution is disabled and the window has an exception. Now i've created another empty window, which had no exceptions and there the toolbar was visible and i could enable code execution.